# I need to create a new data frame where price is more than 500 and body style is equal to sedan

Tags: python, pandas

newdd = (df[(df['body-style'] == 'sedan') & (df['price'] > 500)])

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: The error might be because `df['price']` is string type. You can check the datatypes by `df.dtypes`.

Comment: Try using eval to confirm, and then work around accordingly newdd = (df[(df['body-style'] == 'sedan') & (eval(df['price']) > 500)])

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that df['price'] is not an integer but has some strings in it. You can check this using

```
df['price'].dtypes
```

A typical case would be that you have empty strings ('') when no price is given. If so you can correct this by

```
# Generate Test Set
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['price'] = ['0.0', '', 1.0]

# Repair Data
df.loc[df['price'] == '', 'price'] = None
df['price'] = df['price'].astype('float64')

# Test The Check
df['price'] > 500
```